# Interop to Epplus Convertions Issue. Range not able to set the same scenario for Epplus

Tags: c#, interop, epplus

I want to use the same approach as used above on interop but need to perform in EPPLUS

```
ExcelRange r;
string s = string.empty;

//returns range address (A10:L90)
s = (SValues(ws)) 

//assigns range from row like in : ws.Range[s][1, 1].Row [ws.range["A10:L90][1,1].row // returns count for further use
r = ws.Range[ws.Cells[ws.Range[s][1, 1].Row, 1], ws.Cells[ws.Range[s][1, 1].Row + ws.Range[s].Rows.Count - 1, ws.Range[s][1, 1].Column + ws.Range[s].Columns.Count - 1]];


//setting certain cells to NumberFormat
ws.Range[ws.Cells[r[1, 1].Row, 3], ws.Cells[r[1, 1].Row + r.Rows.Count - 1, r[1, 1].Column + r.Columns.Count - 1]].NumberFormat = "0.00";

//for the range in r sort data based on index []
r.Sort(Key1: r[1, 3], Order1: Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Key2: r[1, r.Columns.Count], Order2: Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Key3: r[1, 2], Order3: Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Header: Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo, OrderCustom: 1, MatchCase: false, Orientation: Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows, DataOption1: Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, DataOption2: Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, DataOption3: Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal
```

I'm aware that EPPLUS uses Lists instead of Arrays used in Interop hence I need to find an alternative to perform this process. I'm developing an application which works on existing Excel Sheets and sorts it, manipulate with rows and columns, check sheets, validate it etc

2nd Question: Need to replicate this interop code to Epplus
    ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[1, 1]].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Offset[-1];

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? what should this code do?

Comment: sorry, still not clear.
can you please update your question instead of comments? and what is s? what is r?

Comment: @YahyaHussein have updated my question

Comment: so "s" should contain range address of cells that have value?

Comment: "r" should contains the count of cells that belong to both above range and row number?

Comment: s would just contain the cell address to be worked on like : "$A$14:$L$680"

Comment: r would have whole tree like ws.Range[s][1, 1].Row  //ws.Range["$A$14:$L$680"][1,1].Row  // here (1,1).Row will be 14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159905/discussion-between-ivan-and-yahya-hussein).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are just setting ranges.   With Epplus, the `Cells` object pulls double duty as IT is a Range.  I am rusty with using Interop but I think this should get you close to what you are looking for (may have to adjust the `- 1`'s if I got the 0-based vs 1-based indexes wrong):

```
//assigns range from row like in : ws.Range[s][1, 1].Row [ws.range["A10:L90][1,1].row // returns count for further use
/*
r = ws.Range
[
    ws.Cells[ws.Range[s][1, 1].Row, 1]
    , ws.Cells[
        ws.Range[s][1, 1].Row + ws.Range[s].Rows.Count - 1
        , ws.Range[s][1, 1].Column + ws.Range[s].Columns.Count - 1
        ]
];
*/

//*****Rough translation with s as any proper Excel string range
var srange = ws.Cells[s];
var startcell = srange.Start;
var endcell = srange[srange.End.Row - 1, srange.End.Column - 1].Start; // or if you just want the end you can do = srange.End

//Reset the indexer
srange = ws.Cells[s];
r = srange[startcell.Row, startcell.Column, endcell.Row, endcell.Column];

//*****From there you can just set formatting as you like

//setting certain cells to NumberFormat
//ws.Range[ws.Cells[r[1, 1].Row, 3], ws.Cells[r[1, 1].Row + r.Rows.Count - 1, r[1, 1].Column + r.Columns.Count - 1]].NumberFormat = "0.00";
r[1, 3, r.End.Row - 1, r.End.Column - 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";

//for the range in r sort data based on index []
//r.Sort(Key1: r[1, 3], Order1: Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Key2: r[1, r.Columns.Count], Order2: Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Key3: r[1, 2], Order3: Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Header: Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo, OrderCustom: 1, MatchCase: false, Orientation: Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows, DataOption1: Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, DataOption2: Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, DataOption3: Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal
r.Sort(new[] {3, r.Columns - 1}, new[] {true, true});
```

---

**RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

Here is a full unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RangeConversionTest()
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo("c:\\temp\\RangeConversionTest.xlsx");
    if (fileInfo.Exists)
        fileInfo.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {
        //Some random data
        var wb = pck.Workbook;
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

        var random = new Random();

        const int rows = 20;
        const int cols = 15;
        for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                if (row == 0 && c == 0)
                    ws.Cells[row + 1, c + 1].Value = null;

                else if (row == 0)
                    ws.Cells[row + 1, c + 1].Value = $"Column {c}";

                else if (c == 0)
                    ws.Cells[row + 1, c + 1].Value = $"Row {row}";
                else
                    ws.Cells[row + 1, c + 1].Value = random.Next(5);
            }
        }

        ExcelRange r;
        string s = "B2:N20";

        var srange = ws.Cells[s];
        var startcell = srange.Start;
        var endcell = srange[srange.End.Row - 1, srange.End.Column - 1].Start;

        srange = ws.Cells[s];
        r = srange[startcell.Row, startcell.Column, endcell.Row, endcell.Column];
        r.Sort(new[] {3, r.Columns - 1}, new[] {true, true});
        r[1, 3, r.End.Row, r.End.Column].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";

        pck.Save();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: hanks I tried this but on line 3 : var endcell.. it would reset the srange to the address set on endcell and therefore make the actual set address of srange no more to use why does it get it removed? and r.sort not getting detected on VS 2015 is on epplus beta only? . Thanks Ernie

Comment: @Ives Yes, sorry, forgot the Epplus like to persist the indexer whenever you access it.  See my edit above, just have to recreate the range.  Which version are you using exactly?  I am using 4.10 and sort is there - VS version should not matter.

Comment: hi, so I tried downgrading to 4.1.0 still it was unable to find. Note r is defined as ExcelRangeBase when in debug. Can you please confirm it works since this FAQ says otherwise : https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14791

Comment: @Ives See my edit with a full unit test.  See if it runs for you.

Comment: Just to update this, turns out the the source code of 4.1 has the sort function (at least in my copy) but not in the nuget package.  So to use the sort funciton you want the 4.5 beta.  See this:  https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/78